# Windows 10 not loading folder items/context menu

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10

I have updated to Windows 10, it was working fine, until it wasn't.

It stopped showing folder data and right click on any folder doesn't work.
Upon opening Downloads folder it keeps loading and never shows the data/files and if i click it, it says Explorer has stopped responding.

**Event Viewer Report:**

```
The program explorer.exe version 10.0.10240.16405 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
    Process ID: 684
    Start Time: 01d0d076200a0a94
    Termination Time: 0
    Application Path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
    Report Id: 44273285-3c6a-11e5-9bc7-0026b9c7c947
    Faulting package full name: 
    Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Also **right click** on any folder makes Explorer go in to `Not Respondng`

This happens every-time. What is wrong with it?

EDIT: Just Noticed can't even load files via Open Dialog

EDIT 2: From what I have heard from my friends, this problem occurs often. And CheckDisk does the trick

Comment: I would back up important files to external drive and [do a clean install of Windows 10 using this tool.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install)

Comment: @Moab I upgraded with the ISO converted from ESD Downloaded from MS Servers.

Comment: The ISOs converted from ESD were for the RTM version, I believe. There is no reason to convert anymore as Microsoft released the official Windows 10 media creation tool.

Comment: @MC10 Mine caused problems, downloaded two times but it failed to create ISO. I grabbed the URL from the Media Tool and downloaded it via a download manager. But that was an ESD so had to convert. BTW doesn't answer my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it wouldn't hurt to run CheckDisk. That did the trick. For those who have similar problem try running

`cmd> chkdsk /F` with Admin privileges

It solved my problem.

Regards

Comment: A little reason regarding the down vote would help others too.